# Hadoop options are not having any effect (mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap, mapred.max.map.failures.percent)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement a MapReduce job, where each of the mappers would take 150 lines of the text file, and all the mappers would run simmultaniously; also, it should not fail, no matter how many map tasks fail.

Here's the configuration part:

```
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(Main.class);
        conf.setJobName("My mapreduce");

        conf.set("mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap", "150");
        conf.set("mapred.max.map.failures.percent","100");

        conf.setInputFormat(NLineInputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
```

The problem is that hadoop creates a mapper for every single line of text, they seem to run sequentially, and if a single one fails, the job fails.

From this I deduce, that the settings I've applied do not have any effect.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to quickly find the correct names for the options for hadoop's new api, use this link: http://pydoop.sourceforge.net/docs/examples/intro.html#hadoop-0-21-0-notes .

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using Hadoop 0.20. In 0.20 the configuration parameter is "mapred.line.input.format.linespermap" and you are using "mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap". If the configuration parameter is not set then it's defaulted to 1, so you so you are seeing the behavior mentioned in the query.

Here is the code snippet from 0.20 NLineInputFormat.

> public void configure(JobConf conf) { N = conf.getInt("mapred.line.input.format.linespermap", 1); }

Hadoop configuration is sometimes a real pain, not documented properly and I have observed that the configuration parameter also keeps changing sometimes between releases. The best bet is to see the code when uncertain of some configuration parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can't wait till 0.21 comes out! )

Comment: 0.21 is already out, but is not stable. There is a discussion going on in Hadoop around release 0.22 and 0.23 with some nice features will be released some time next year. I am not aware of the migration path for 0.20 users. Maybe you can raise a separate query on the migration path for 0.20 users.

Comment: I'm having an other problem right now. What I am writing is actually an indexing app. The mapper sends a request, and spends most of its time waiting for the response. At this moment, hadoop executes only 2 mappers per mashine. I believe, that this slows the app considerably down. How do I tell it to run at least 100 mappers parallely?

Comment: Open another query with more details :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471289/how-to-tell-mapreduce-how-many-mappers-to-use-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 1):

To start with "mapred.*" is old api and "mapreduce.*" is new api. so you would better not use them together. check which version you are using and stick with that. And also recheck your imports, since there are 2 NLineInputFormat aswell (mapred and mapreduce).

Secondly you can check this [link](http://old.nabble.com/NLine-Input-Format-td20515297.html) : (gonna paste the important part)

*NLineInputFormat will split N lines of input as one split. So, each map
gets N lines.*

*But the RecordReader is still LineRecordReader, which reads one line at
time, thereby Key is the offset in the file and Value is the line.
If you want N lines as Key, you may to override LineRecordReader.*

Comment: hey. New api for hadoop 0.20 does not contain NLineInputFormat, and there is no 0.21 installed at any of the clusters I can use. I don't want N lines as a Key. I'd like the map being called sequentially with [random] 150 lines from the text file

Comment: you need to be sure that you are not using old and new api together, that really would mix up things. as I see from your configs I can see that you are mixing them. use "mapred.line.input.format.linespermap" or "mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent" depending of which api you are using. stick with "mapred" or "mapreduce" in both imports and configs

Answer (score 0):

The new api's options are mostly undocumented