# How to tell MapReduce how many mappers to use at the same time?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing an indexing app for MapReduce.
I was able to split inputs with NLineInputFormat, and now I've got few hundred mappers in my app. However, only 2/mashine of those are active at the same time, the rest are "PENDING". I believe that such a behavior slows the app significantly.

How do I make hadoop run at least 100 of those at the same time per machine?

I am using the old hadoop api syntax. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    conf.setNumMapTasks(1000);
    conf.setNumTasksToExecutePerJvm(500);
```

none of those seem to have any effect.

Any ideas how I can make the mappers actually RUN in parallel?

Comment: What about using n-lines which is actually 1/100 from your input lines? Why don't you use the file size splitting by Hadoop?

Comment: Right now I'm in testing mode, where I've got only 5000 lines in the input file. If I use hadoop's splitting, it executes it with a single mapper. As far as I'm concerned, that is not a desirable behavior. Even in the end case, where the input file will have a size of 3.5 GB, the hadoop's default segment size of 64-128 MB will result in too few mappers for the optimal performance of the application. A mapper spends most of its time waiting for the response from the website

Comment: How many nodes do you have on your cluster?  Keep in mind that by default a task takes up 200MB of memory.  If you're expecting to run a large amount of tasks on a node, you'll encounter OutOfMemoryErrors.  Also keep in mind that there is a certain amount of overhead associated with setting up a task.  More tasks do not necessarily amount to better performance.

Comment: I did run the test on a combination consisting of 1 master node and 2 slave nodes. which summed up to 4 simultaneously running mappers

Answer (score 2):

The [JobConf.setNumMapTasks()](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setNumMapTasks%28int%29) is just a hint to the MR framework and I am not sure the effect of calling it. In your case the total number of map tasks across the whole job should be equal to the total number of lines in the input divided by the number of lines configured in the NLineInputFormat. You can find more details on the total number of map/reduce tasks across the whole job [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces).

The description for [mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred-default.html) says

> The maximum number of map tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.

You need to configure the mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum (which is defaulted to 2) to change the number of map tasks run parallely on a particular node by the task tracker. I could not get the documentation for 0.20.2, so I am not sure if the parameter exists or if the same parameter name is used in 0.20.2 release.

Comment: no, this one does not change the number of simultaneously active map tasks

Comment: As I mentioned I don't have access to the 0.20.2 code right now. Check the TTConfig.java and the TaskTracker.java and look for TT_MAP_SLOTS. As someone said if want to get the HD (High Definition) view of Hadoop, the best bet is code :)