# Elaborate multiple line in a single map function

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working on hadoop and I want that every map function works on more lines than one. I found that I can use the property mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap, but if I have understand it, with this I can specify the number of line for single mapper and not for every map function. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7457292/3959454) will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you will have to write your custom text format .

2) you will have to create your own custom record reader for that ,where you will implement the logic.

```
You will extend from  TextInputFormat class to create your own NLinesInputFormat .
You will also create your own RecordReader class called NLinesRecordReader where you will implement the logic of feeding 3 lines/records at a time.
You will make a change in our driver program to use our new NLinesInputFormat class.
please follow the link for complete details :
```

please follow the below link for detailed approach :
http://bigdatacircus.com/2012/08/01/wordcount-with-custom-record-reader-of-textinputformat/